# wpf ribbon control, can i put ribbonTab in quickaccesstolbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Can I put RibbonTab in QuickAccessToolBar?

I want to create tab like google chrome and firefox 4

Comment: so can someone help me to create tab like google chrome?

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt anyone would do this for you. You would likely have to do it yourself, pay someone to do it, or wait until someone decides to create an opensource implementation.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Also, I believe it is against the [Ribbon UI guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx), which are rather strict on how the various elements are to be used (I believe the Ribbon UI is licensed under a royalty-free license from Microsoft that dictates these guidelines are to be followed).

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, no. The RibbonTab is intended to mimic the tabs seen in the Microsoft Office Ribbon.